# Duplicate Wallet

Tags: exchanges

I had a wallet on an exchange. For a few months I was using it with no trouble. Then one day I sent some BTC to it and it never showed up in the wallet on the exchange. I can see it in bitcoin explorer though. I can also send from the wallet on the exchange to an offline wallet...

Comment: "Then one day I sent some BTC to it and it never showed up in the wallet on the exchange." and "I can also send from the wallet on the exchange to an offline wallet" contradicts each other.

Comment: How? I said duplicate wallet addresses. You can check this address 1JG6QGxpS4wWk5ERw2F8mg5QHLjtd2w45Y on bitcoin explorer. Yet, when I access the wallet from the exchange, it does not show the BTC. I was fully able to send to an offline wallet from the exchange. But if you send to that address it will not show up on the exchange.